# Are there any virtual ethernet switches for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, networking, virtualization

I need a way to connect 2 virtual machines on my Windows 7 laptop.

I would like to use a virtual ethernet switch, is there such a thing for Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Workstation, you have three options for the network connectivity of your VMs (not counting custom setups):

-Bridge mode:This connects the virtual netwoirk adapter directly to the physical network

-NAT: This allows the virtual netwoirk adapter to share the host’s IP address

-Host Only: This creates a private network that the virtual network adapter shares with the host

It sounds like you want to communicate between VMs and possibly with the outside world.  That would be Bridge Mode.  To change the network adapter settings, click on the VM, select "Settings".  On the Hardware tab, click on the adapter you need to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Windows 7 has no virtualization technology it obviously has no virtual ether et swich.

Whatever you use there to run the virtual machines surely has some name and documentation so you can read up how to set networking in there. Or do you run the vm's by staring at an operating system without virtualization? ;)

Comment: I am running VMware Workstation 8. I sort of have it working but it intermittently fails.